# How to add imported libraries into setup.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

I have a project in which I have imported different python libraries using `pip install <library>` I see I can create setup.py for that, but I couldn't exactly figure it out. So I have to add all imported libraries in packages? e.g.   `packages=['requests', 're']`

Can I use it to install python if user doesn't have it?
Or I just add python files which I have defined into packages? e.g. test1.py, test2.py
**edit**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='Testproject',
      version='0.1',
      description='testing',
      author='tester',
      packages=['requests', 'subprocess'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Comment: *"I have to add all imported libraries in packages?"* - all the ones you actually need to run it, yes. *"Can I use it to install python if user doesn't have it"* - no, you need Python to run `setup.py` so that wouldn't make sense.

Comment: I ran as above but I get error `error: package directory 'requests' does not exist` Because it's not my module, it's in built python module? Do I have to give path for that?

Comment: `packages` is for the packages **your code defines**, not its dependencies. Have you considered running through a tutorial or worked example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `install_requires` to for dependencies:

http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distributing/?highlight=install_requires#install-requires

> “install_requires” should be used to specify what dependencies a
>   project minimally needs to run. When the project is installed by pip,
>   this is the specification that is used to install its dependencies.